# Can't post data to MongoDB from React-native application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, express

I have a two part question. I am trying to add data from a react-native modal to MongoDB. The second part of the question is, I need to add the data into the user entry in the DB, each user will have a record of additional data from this form. I'm not sure how to to that. This is my first time using MongoDB.

I have used the same structure used to create user's but when I submit the form data, nothing happens.

Package Details Form

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  Picker,
  View,
  Image,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  Button
} from "react-native";
import { Input, CheckBox, Divider } from "react-native-elements";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view";
import axios from "axios";
import baseUrl from "../baseUrl";
axios.defaults.baseURL = baseUrl;

export default class DisplayModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      display: false,
      recipient_name: "",
      weight: "",
      fragile: false,
      urgent: false,
      additional: ""
    };
  }

  setModalVisible() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ display: !prevState.display }));
  }

  setStateUtil = (property, value = undefined) => {
    this.setState({
      [property]: value
    });
  };

  async handlePackage() {
    try {
      const {
        recipient_name,
        weight,
        fragile,
        urgent,
        additional
      } = this.state;
      await axios.post("/package", {
        recipient_name,
        weight,
        fragile,
        urgent,
        additional
      });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: error.response.data.message });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const props = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={this.props.display}
        animationType="slide"
        onRequestClose={() => console.log("closed")}
        recipient_name={this.state.recipient_name}
        fragile={this.state.fragile}
        urgent={this.state.urgent}
        additional={this.state.additional}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
            <View>
              <Input
                placeholder="Recipient Name"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                value={this.state.recipient_name}
                onChangeText={changedRecipientName =>
                  this.setStateUtil("recipient_name", changedRecipientName)
                }
              />

              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text style={styles.heading}>Package Weight</Text>
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={this.state.language}
                  style={{
                    height: 50,
                    width: 130,
                    marginLeft: 20,
                    marginTop: 11
                  }}
                  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                    this.setState({ language: itemValue })
                  }
                  value={this.state.weight}
                  onChangeText={weight =>
                    this.state.handleChange("weight", weight)
                  }
                >
                  <Picker.Item label="1-5kg" value="one" />
                  <Picker.Item label="6-10kg" value="six" />
                  <Picker.Item label="10-20kg" value="ten" />
                </Picker>
              </View>

              <CheckBox
                title="Fragile"
                onPress={() =>
                  this.setState({
                    fragile: !this.state.fragile
                  })
                }
                checked={this.state.fragile}
                value={this.state.fragile}
                onChangeText={fragile =>
                  this.state.handleChange("fragile", fragile)
                }
              />
              <CheckBox
                onPress={() =>
                  this.setState({
                    urgent: !this.state.urgent
                  })
                }
                title="Urgent"
                checked={this.state.urgent}
                value={this.state.urgent}
              />

              <Text style={styles.headingInfo}>Additional Info</Text>

              <TextInput
                style={{
                  height: 180,
                  marginLeft: 18,
                  marginRight: 18,
                  marginBottom: 18,
                  textAlignVertical: "top",
                  borderWidth: 0.3,
                  padding: 10
                }}
                placeholder="Please add any additional info"
                value={this.state.additional}
                onChangeText={changedAdditional =>
                  this.setStateUtil("additional", changedAdditional)
                }
              />
              <View style={{ height: 60 }} />
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center"
              }}
            >
              <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 18 }}>
                <Button
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.props.triggerModal();
                  }}
                  title="Continue"
                  color="green"
                />
              </View>
              <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 18 }}>
                <Button
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.handlePackage();
                    this.props.triggerModal();
                  }}
                  title="Cancel"
                  color="red"
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 23,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  headingInfo: {
    fontSize: 23,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20
  },
  buttonContinue: {
    marginBottom: 30
  }
});
```

controllers/package.js

```
const Package = require("../model/Package");

exports.getPackages = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const packageFromDb = await Package.find({});
    const package = packageFromDb.map(
      ({
        recipientName,
        Package_Weight,
        Fragile,
        Urgent,
        Additional_Note
      }) => ({
        recipientName,
        Package_Weight,
        Fragile,
        Urgent,
        Additional_Note
      })
    );
    return res.json({ package });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

model/Package.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const packageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  recipientName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  package_Weight: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  fragile: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  urgent: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  additional_Note: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const Package = mongoose.model("Package", packageSchema);

module.exports = Package;
```

routes/package.js

```
const express = require("express");
const packageController = require("../controllers/package");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", packageController.getPackages);

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoDbConnectionString = require("./config/mongodb");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const userRouter = require("./routes/users");
const packageRouter = require("./routes/package");
const authMiddleware = require("./middleware/auth");
const errorMiddleware = require("./middleware/error");
const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("*", authMiddleware);
app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/package", packageRouter);
app.use(errorMiddleware);

mongoose
  .connect(
    mongoDbConnectionString,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(result => {
    console.log("Connected to Mongodb");
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("Server is listening on PORT: " + PORT);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

controllers/auth.js

```
const User = require("../model/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtSecret = require("../config/jwtSecret");

exports.loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
      if (isPasswordCorrect) {
        const token = jwt.sign({ email: user.email }, jwtSecret);
        return res.json({ token });
      }
      const error = new Error(`Password does not match email ${email}`);
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    const error = new Error(`This email ${email} does not exist`);
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};

exports.createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;

    if (await User.findOne({ email })) {
      const error = new Error(
        `An account with the mail ${email} already exists`
      );
      error.statusCode = 409;
      throw error;
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    const user = new User({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword
    });
    const result = await user.save();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

middleware/auth.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const jwtSecret = require("../config/jwtSecret");

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.get("Authorization");
  if (!authHeader) {
    const error = new Error("Authorization header missing token");
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  }

  try {
    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    err.statusCode = 401;
    throw err;
  }
  next();
};
```

controllers/users.js

```
const User = require("../model/User");

exports.getUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const usersFromDb = await User.find({});
    const users = usersFromDb.map(({ firstName, lastName, email }) => ({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email
    }));
    return res.json({ users });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

I expect the data to be added to the database in the same way the users are added (the users are added correctly). The missing code would allow the package data to be added to each user adding the details but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If I use Postman to test the API / endpoint (http://localhost:4000/package/), I get this response in postman - "message": "jwt must be provided" and the same response in my NodeJS terminal. I've used the JWT token generated in postman with the email and password for the Authorization header but still the error persists.

Comment: Do you send "Bearer  YOUR_TOKEN" in Authorization header in postman?